# How to use custom theme correctly with component lib that uses Material UI (I don't want to wrap with them all components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design, react-component

How to use custom theme correctly with component lib that uses Material UI (I don't want to wrap with them all components).

import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: '#1976d2'
      },
      success: {
        main: '#4caf50'
      }
    },
    typography: {
      fontSize: 16,
      h3: {
        fontWeight: 700,
        fontSize: '2.2rem'
      },
      h4: {
        fontWeight: 700,
        fontSize: '1.75rem'
      },
      h5: {
        fontWeight: 500
      },
      h6: {
        fontWeight: 500
      }
    }
  })

  export default theme;
```

I have only one index file where export all my components as usual lib does. How can I wrap all my components with the theme without doing it everywhere? Or is there better way to customize styles?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your App.tsx file (or _app.tsx if you use Next.js) in ThemeProvider and provide your theme:
https://mui.com/customization/theming/

Comment: I don't have app.tsx this is component lib I just have index.ts where all components are exported

Comment: User of your component library need to do this